# Meteor Mongo onRendered .count() incorrectly returning value

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor, I'm trying to set a session variable in the onRendered template function. Specifically, I want to count the number of documents that are returned from the MongoDB collection by using `Meteor.users.find({}).count()` and storing it in the session variable:

**admin.js**

```
Template.admin.helpers({
    users() {
        var skip = Session.get('adminUserListPageCurrent');
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {limit: 1, skip: skip});
    },
    pages() {
        return Meteor.users.find({}).count();
    }
});

Template.admin.onRendered(function () {
    var users = Meteor.users.find({}).count();
    Session.set('adminUserNumberOfPages', users);
});
```

In total, there are three user accounts; however, it returns a value of zero in the onRendered template function.  Contrarily, it correctly returns the value in my template helper.

Comment: This code runs client side.  When your onRendered function is executing, there are 0 documents in the Meteor.users miniMongo collection, because it hasn't received the data from the server yet.

Comment: Just a side note that there should be no need to create a Session variable from a cursor count since `Meteor.users.find({}).count()` is itself a reactive data source and will update any dependency automatically. You're seeing different values simply because the subscription isn't ready yet when you first ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the data is available in the meteor.Users collection on the client.  This code uses [autorun](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun) to update your Session variable when the client receives the data, (and future updates).  If you want this to just run once on startup, you could try using [Meteor.setTimeout](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout)

```
Template.admin.onRendered(function () {
  console.log('Initially in onRendered: ', Meteor.users.find({}).count());

  this.autorun(() => {
    var users = Meteor.users.find({}).count();
    Session.set('adminUserNumberOfPages', users);
    console.log('In autorun: ', Meteor.users.find({}).count());
  });

});
```

Comment: Just a note to others reading the answer: beware that function inside this.autorun() will run whenever the data inside `Meteor.users` collection changes, so it might be 0, 1, 2, 3, or might be 0, 3 (depending on speed at which data comes)